# Display an activity for certain time before other activity

Tags: android, adt

I have a task to make a splash screen that show up for 5 seconds and afer that login screen should appear. So , I have a made a main activity as a splash screen and login activity that  displays the login form. 
In the onCreate function of main activity I have set the thread.sleep(5000) function after the setContentView function and then load the login activity.
But the problem is that the main activity content doesnot appear.

So where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. Please check this out.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.os.Message;

import android.view.Window;
import com.om.utils.Constant;
import com.om.utils.Utils;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    private static final int GoNextActivity = 1988;
    private static final int FinishThisActivity = 1989;
    private Intent intent = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);



        if (Utils.isOnline(Splash.this)) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(GoNextActivity, 2000);
        } else {
            Utils.displayToast(Splash.this, Constant.NO_NETWORK_CONNECTION);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(FinishThisActivity, 2000);
        }
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (msg.what) {
            case GoNextActivity:
                intent = new Intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;
            case FinishThisActivity:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a delayed handler for this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //launch new activity here

        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call Thread.sleep(5000) method in onCreate(), it blocks your main UI thread from doing anything. It waits on sleep instruction for 5 seconds. It do not allow app to create the View for your splash activity. After sleep instruction, I guess, you are launching your home activity. So it happens in quick succession and second activity comes in front. That is why you are unable to see anything on splash activity.
One more thing, use postDelayed(Runnable, timeInMillis) method to show splash screen and launch your main activity after timeInMillis interval.